# n98-magerun doesn't throw errors?

Tags: cli, command-line

I am working on a magerun command, but it seems that errors are not triggered. E.g.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface
$output)
{
    $this->detetMagento($output);
}
```

If I misspell detectMagento and run the command, it does nothing, I would expect an Exception to be thrown or some other error triggered... There's also nothing in the logs. Obviously, this doesn't work really well ;)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Makes developing a magerun command quite hard, doesn't it? Almost hard to believe...

Comment: I cannot confirm this statement. We do not catch fatal errors or change any error settings of PHP. I checked the issue in n98-magerun1 and n98-magerun2. I got always a PHP fatal error with a complete call stack.

Comment: Tnx, good to know. Will probably be at my end then. Any ideas what this might be causing?

Comment: Solved. Using MAMP Pro and the php .ini file used in the command line is different than the one for web. display_errors = On solves the issue...